# VS 2015 Xamarin - Can't use iOS storyboard designer after running in debug/simulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I started a new, empty Xamarin iOS project. When I edit the Main.storyboard, the designer pops up, no problem. But once I run the iOS simulator I can no longer edit the storyboard without error. It doesn't matter if I stop debug, detach from the simulator, close the storyboard and reopen; I have to completely close Visual Studio (2015) and reopen the solution in order to get the storyboard designer to render so I can work with it.

I'm on stable branch. Any ideas? Here's the error I get:

> ERROR: EnsureSession (counter 1): MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Session invalid
>      at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest(CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning)
>      at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.PostXml(DesignSession session, String xml, String[] viewsToHide)
>      at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.PostXml(DesignSession session, XElement fullStoryboard, XElement[] partialElements, Boolean freezeMisplacements, String[] viewsToHide)
>      at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<>c__DisplayClass162_0.b__0(ServerProcessConnection c)
>      at MonoTouch.Design.Client.IPhoneDesignerSession.<>c__DisplayClass237_1`1.b__0()
>
> [2016-08-31 00:10:13.6] INFO: Reloading: Serialization took 0ms
>
> [2016-08-31 00:10:13.9] WARN: Failure #1 (IOException) while sending web request. Retrying..
>
> [2016-08-31 00:10:13.9] INFO: Reloading: Serialization took 0ms
>
> [2016-08-31 00:10:14.7] WARN: Failure #2 (IOException) while sending web request. Retrying..
>
> [2016-08-31 00:10:14.7] INFO: Reloading: Serialization took 0ms
>
> [2016-08-31 00:10:14.9] ERROR: Unrecoverable IOException.. Spin up attempts: 0, failure retries: 3
>   System.IO.EndOfStreamException: We could not fully deserialize the response ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Attempting to deserialize an empty stream.

Edit: The only workaround I've found is to disconnect from the Mac Agent, close the designer, then reopen the designer which prompts you to reconnect to the Mac Agent. It's a tad faster than just closing VS entirely but not ideal.

Comment: Can you post your version info in a gist (https://gist.github.com/)? VS: Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio -> Copy Info. Mac: Xamarin Studio -> About Xamarin Studio -> Show Details -> Copy Information

Comment: The workaround didn't work by my side. Keep the error of IOException. VS 2015 Pro 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 and MAC: Version 6.1.3 (build 19) Mono 4.6.2 - Xcode 8.2.1 (11766.1)

Answer (score 0):

Your workaround didn't work for me. My error was certainly different.

If you get this error you can take a look on log into:
C:\Users{USER}\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Logs\14.0

In this file I add a more detailed error why my storyboard didn't opened:

> Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient Error: 0 : [2016-12-27
>   15:27:39.5593] An error occured on the receiver while executing a post
>   for topic xvs/Designer/4.2.2.6/send-payload and client vs130
>   Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingRemoteException: An error
>   occured on client Designer4226 while executing a reply for topic
>   xvs/Designer/4.2.2.6/send-payload ---> System.NotSupportedException:
>   Couldn't find a DeviceConfig for [ConnectionAttributes: Device=Pad,
>   SdkPath=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk,
>   SdkVersion=10.1, ViewAs=Default]

Decoding this error is easier. It seems that my project was build for iOS 10.1 and my Xcode had only iOS 10.2 installed.

I opened Xcode and went into simulator and created a new device with iOS 10.1 simulator.

Closing the storyboard and opening it back and all was working as expected